# Getting a this.SetDynamic is not a function error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

While trying to run a project I'm running into this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                              7:24:33 PM

 error  in ./src/main.js

Syntax Error: TypeError: /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/src/main.js: this.setDynamic is not a function
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)


ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/src/main.js: this.setDynamic is not a function
    at PluginPass.pre (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-runtime/lib/index.js:31:12)
    at transformFile (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:73:27)
    at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:24:12)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
    at /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
    at /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:189:28
    at /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:68:7
    at /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:113:33
    at step (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:287:14)
    at /Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/App/imagecapture/App-ic/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
```

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './vuetify'
import { createDriveClient } from './drive-utils'
import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Load Google API client and authorize app
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
  gapi.client.init({
    clientId: 'CLIENT-ID',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
  }).then(() => {
    // Set up drive client
    const driveClient = createDriveClient()

    // Pass driveClient instance to app
    new Vue({
      router,
      vuetify,
      mounted () {
        const setDynamic = (Vue) => {
          Vue.mixin({
            beforeCreate () {
              const options = this.$options
              if (options.dynamicProps) {
                const data = options.data
                options.data = function () {
                  return {
                    ...(typeof data === 'function' ? data.call(this) : data),
                    propsData: {}
                  }
                }
                options.computed = options.computed || {}
                Object.keys(options.dynamicProps).forEach(key => {
                  options.computed[key] = function () {
                    return this.propsData[key] !== undefined
                      ? this.propsData[key]
                      : options.dynamicProps[key]
                  }
                })
              }
            },
            mounted () {
              const propsData = {}
              const options = this.$options
              Object.keys(options.dynamicProps || {}).forEach(key => {
                propsData[key] = this[key]
                delete this[key]
              })
              this.propsData = propsData
            }
          })
        }

        setDynamic(Vue)

        // Render app
        this.$mount('#app')
      },
      render: h => h(App, { props: { driveClient } })
    })
  })
})
```

I can't seem to figure out how to resolve this could someone point me in the correct direction.

I've tried different variations and suggestions listed in other threads to no avail, as I'm doing a new build, I shouldn't have an version issue, so it would be based on the latest version available and not updating to a new version as some of the threads are suggesting (v6 --> v7)